# Count all values with a same DATE entry - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have an *events* table in the following Schema:

id

name (String)

created_at (DateTime)

description (String)

The events should be grouped by the day they happened and counted

I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DATE(events.created_at)             AS day,
  description                         AS description,
  COUNT(*)                            AS count
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE name = 'trained'
GROUP BY day, events.id
ORDER BY day ASC``
```

But this is always returning 1 as *count*,

I tried some variations regarding **COUNT( )** and **GROUP BY** but none of them worked

Comment: Don't group by events.id

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

hope help you

```
SELECT DATE(events.created_at) AS day,
COUNT(description) AS count
FROM EVENTS 
WHERE name = 'trained'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC``
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine, I misread ( and tought that that I had to use events.id, when in fact I had to use events.description as a *must*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      DATE(events.created_at)             AS day,
      description                         AS description,
      COUNT(*)                            AS count
    FROM EVENTS 
    WHERE name = 'trained'
    GROUP BY day, events.description
    ORDER BY day ASC
```

But thank you everyone for your help, I really appreciate your time